# Date Hierarchy not showing up Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am doing an internship as data scientist and my boss is giga mad at me cause I had to remake a PBIx panel and I am not able to see the date hierarchy as it should appear in the old one. Both columns has the same format and the same numbers in Power Query (date) but she told me the hierarchy would be automatically implemented. I dont really know what to do. Any idea?

On the left is the old one, and on the right, the new one.

Thank you all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzmqF.png)

Comment: https://rb.gy/ccmoji for your boss. ;)

Comment: hehe, she kinda rude sometimes but they made her responsible on me and I am giga noob with PBI so I feel her sometimes when she has to "deal with the intern".

Answer (score 1):

Power BI will often make a date hiërarchy by itself.

When that is not the case, you can:

- Right click the date that needs the hiërarchy
- Press 'create hiërarchy'

Picture for reference:

[image: Creating date hiërarchy]

Comment: It only create a normal hierarchy, not a date hierarchy. So that option doesnt work. I need the auto/default one cause its the one that inputs semester/day/week by default. And it is kinda sure that i am making a mistake somehow... But thanks for ur kind reply.

Comment: You can add columns to the hiërarchy and get the same effect. 
Just click on for example year, create hiërarchy, click on month, add to hiërarchy etc. 
Hope it helps! I will edit my question to specify it more!

Comment: My bad, I missed the fact that you only have dates in your fact tables.
Mind that it is bad practice to make date hiërarchies in fact tables, you should join them on a dimensional date table.

Comment: Also, might it be possible your date hiërarchies went away because you made a relation between a datedim and factable? This causes hierarchies to disappear. And sorry for my comment spam, I am a minute too late twice to edit...

Comment: Hey don't say sorry, thank you for taking your time replying my question. So in case I made  a relation between a datedim and factable, is there any way to solve it? 

And thank you again!

Comment: You could delete the relationship, that would get the hiërarchy back. Then at least the dashboard would function again as intended. But, I suggest using a dimDate table, but try to work out how it will impact all the dashboards first.